# Can Cassanda aggregate LINQ expression in its query?

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax-csharp-driver

I am quite new to Cassandra so I have a question that I can not find answer to. In EF Core I can pass a list of LINQ expression as conditions and aggregate them so I can find what I need for example:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDataStream(List<Expression<Func<Model, bool>>> predicates)
{
    var query = _context.Model.AsQueryable();
    if (predicates != null)
    {
        query = predicates.Aggregate(query, (@event, condition) => @event.Where(condition));
    }
    return await query.Select(data => data.).ToListAsync();
}
```

Now I am wondering if there is a such possibility in Cassandra. I tried:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Model>> Find(List<Expression<Func<Model, bool>>> predicates, int assetId)
{
    IQueryable<Model> query = _table.AsQueryable();
    if (predicates != null)
    {
        query = predicates.Aggregate(query, (@event, condition) => @event.Where(condition));
    }

    return await query.Select(data => data); // here is a problem dont know ow to execute this
}
```

So is such a thing possible?

EDIT:

So I tried with aggregate combination

query.Select(d => d).Execute();

also  and got this exception in result

> The expression Call
> = [SELECT gap_end, gap_start, uuid FROM gaps_state_data.Where(data => (data.EndValue == null))]
> is not supported in None parse phase.

It looks expression aggregate is not being format for some reason.

Comment: What library are you using? Have you tried just executing the query synchronously? `var results = query.Select(data => data).ToList();`

Comment: I am using https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver

Comment: So it looks like you need to call `query.Select(d => d).Execute();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured this one out, using hint in comments, let me show full code of this and how it should work:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Model>> Find(List<Expression<Func<Model, bool>>> predicates)
{
    CqlQuery<Model> query = _table.Select(d => d);

    if (predicates != null)
    {
        query = predicates.Aggregate(query, (@event, condition) => @event.Where(condition));
    }

    return query.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

As I needed to replace table type with `IQueryable`, but when I do this early on like `_table.AsQueryable()` select expression compiled itself. So I needed start expression that will change table to `IQueryable` and that is the role of that `Select()`. Afterwards I could add expressions from parameter.

Comment: Nicely done!  Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but I'm glad you figured it out! For future reference keep in mind that LINQ support in the DataStax C# Driver is very limited compared to what you may be used to when using Entity Framework.

Looking at your use case, I'm not sure if the driver is able to chain `.Where()` calls and generate a CQL query from that. I believe that in the snippet of your answer the driver will run those `Where()` calls locally after the full result set has been received and I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm, as I checked expression builder he ads those were, and it looks somehow like SELECT id, value WHERE id = ? AND value = ? ALLOW FILTERING but to make sure I will investigate more.

Comment: I checked and the chained `.Where()` calls seem to work but whether the query requires `ALLOW FILTERING` or not will depend on your schema. You can add `.AllowFiltering()` if you require it but this is generally not recommended in production workloads.

Comment: I added a full example to my answer. It's the code snippet that I used to test this use case.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Model>> Find(Table<Model> table, List<Expression<Func<Model, bool>>> predicates)
{
    CqlQuery<Model> query = table;
    if (predicates != null)
    {
        query = predicates.Aggregate(query, (@event, condition) => @event.Where(condition));
    }
    return await query.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

It is basically the same as your answer but you don't actually need the `.Select()` part, you just need to cast the table to a `CqlQuery<Model>` object.

Here's the full example that I used to test this (keep in mind that this snippet creates and drops a keyspace and table):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Cassandra;
using Cassandra.Data.Linq;
using Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes;

using Exception = System.Exception;

namespace OssSandbox
{
    public class ProgramLinq
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cassandra.Diagnostics.CassandraTraceSwitch.Level = TraceLevel.Info;
            Trace.AutoFlush = true;
            using var cluster = Cassandra.Cluster.Builder()
                .AddContactPoint(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9042))
                .Build();

            using var session = cluster.Connect();

            session.CreateKeyspaceIfNotExists("ks1", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "class", "SimpleStrategy"}, { "replication_factor", "1"} });

            var table = new Table<Model>(session);
            session.Execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ks1.Model");
            table.CreateIfNotExists();

            table.Insert(new Model { Id = 1, Value1 = "1", Value2 = "2", Value3 = "3" }).Execute();
            table.Insert(new Model { Id = 1, Value1 = "1", Value2 = "2", Value3 = "23" }).Execute();
            table.Insert(new Model { Id = 1, Value1 = "1", Value2 = "22", Value3 = "23" }).Execute();
            table.Insert(new Model { Id = 1, Value1 = "21", Value2 = "22", Value3 = "23" }).Execute();
            table.Insert(new Model { Id = 1, Value1 = "31", Value2 = "32", Value3 = "33" }).Execute();
            table.Insert(new Model { Id = 1, Value1 = "41", Value2 = "42", Value3 = "43" }).Execute();
            table.Insert(new Model { Id = 2, Value1 = "221", Value2 = "222", Value3 = "223" }).Execute();

            var results1 = Find(table, new List<Expression<Func<Model, bool>>>
            {
                m => m.Id == 1,
                m => m.Value1 == "1",
                m => m.Value2 == "2",
            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            PrintRowsResult(results1, "Id == 1 && Value1 == 1 && Value2 == 2");
        }

        public static void PrintRowsResult(IEnumerable<Model> results, string query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(query);
            Console.WriteLine();
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine();

                foreach (var row in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Id: " + row.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("Value1: " + row.Value1);
                    Console.WriteLine("Value2: " + row.Value2);
                    Console.WriteLine("Value3: " + row.Value3);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("####### ERROR: " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<Model>> Find(Table<Model> table, List<Expression<Func<Model, bool>>> predicates)
        {
            CqlQuery<Model> query = table;
            if (predicates != null)
            {
                query = predicates.Aggregate(query, (@event, condition) => @event.Where(condition));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(query.ToString()); // just for debug purposes
            return await query.ExecuteAsync();
        }

        [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.Table(Keyspace = "ks1")]
        public class Model
        {
            [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.PartitionKey]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.ClusteringKey(0)]
            public string Value1 { get; set; }

            [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.ClusteringKey(1)]
            public string Value2 { get; set; }

            [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.ClusteringKey(2)]
            public string Value3 { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fascinating, Ill try it out and compare this with mine :)